# How do you disable the notification alert sounds in the new Google Hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts, mute

I found the new Google Hangouts sounds annoying and they don't provide a way to disable them. The only thing you can do is **disable notifications entirely**, *per contact* even, not globally.

How can you just mute the sound alerts for new messages?

Comment: You can disable them globally with the options in the drop-down next to your name.

Comment: Yes, but that's only [temporary](http://i.imgur.com/YPoVjiC.png), for up to 48 hours.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google now offers an option to mute sounds:

> This setting applies to all Hangouts notifications from Gmail, Google+
>   and the Chrome extension on the same desktop computer.
>
> Turn sound off for notification sounds
>
> - Click menu ▼ at the top of your Hangouts list.
> - Check the box next to "Mute."

From: [Google Hangouts - Turn off notification sounds](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3274605)

Comment: Awesome! They finally added the option! *Mute* wasn't there until recently. Screenshots: [Before](http://i.imgur.com/TtsTD8k.png)/[After](http://i.imgur.com/WQHYSxe.png)

Answer (score 8):

**Edit 2013/12/16:** they added an option to mute all sounds, indefinitely. Finally! [See this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/53231/40770)

---

As of today (2013/05/21), you can't (even though it's [requested](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plus-discuss/dXc7iSDsEpA)), but I found a way to prevent the sound to be loaded and therefore played.

**In short:** I *redirect* the link to the alert audio file (which you can find at the bottom of the answer) to a non-existent one.

This is how:

1. Download the extension [Redirector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirector/lacckjdlmkdhcacjdodpjokfobckjclh) from the Chrome Web Store
2. visit:
   `chrome-extension://lacckjdlmkdhcacjdodpjokfobckjclh/html/options.html#ruleMgr`
3. click on **[+]**
4. set it like in this screenshot
5. save
6. you might have to restart Chrome (or the Hangouts extensions)

[image: Rule editor screenshot]

Text to enter:

```
ssl.gstatic.com/*
incoming_message_eb39ce414e3ffba41a8e173581dc7248
```

To see if it works, try this url, it shouldn't load

```
https://ssl.gstatic.com/chat/sounds/incoming_message_eb39ce414e3ffba41a8e173581dc7248.mp3
```

Comment: Someone could wrap this up in an extension but I suppose (hope) Google will fix it soon, so it's temporary.

Comment: I'm going to try this but with adblock and just blocking the URL to the mp3.

Comment: You're totally right, crdx, you should add that as an answer! I don't know how I didn't think of that considering how many custom filters I have

Comment: Actually… I tried blocking it with AdBlock: it works in Gmail, but not in the Hangouts extension. Maybe AdBlock doesn't work inside `chrome-extension://` pages

Comment: Yeah, it probably doesn't. I don't use the extension so I'm just going the adblock route. I'll add it as an answer as well, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Use your favourite adblock plugin to block the URL to the mp3, which at the time of writing is:

```
https://ssl.gstatic.com/chat/sounds/incoming_message_eb39ce414e3ffba41a8e173581dc7248.mp3
```

In Chrome this appears to only work in web interfaces, and not in the browser extension.